# vsftpd, ProFTPD FTP with windows 10 connection issue

Tags: ftp, windows-10, vsftpd, proftpd

I have one server, Linux based, I use for some years like a backup cloud server. This work very well with client like *Windows 7*, *Ubuntu* and *Android*. But Not with *Windows 10*.
All programs I'ave used for connection work well without problem from years with this clients.
Now I would like connect another computer for online backup with SyncBackFree or freefilesync on windows 10 operative system
and I'ave problem with FTP connection.
To do a test I also tried the ftp connection with filezilla and even here with win 10 I find the same problem.

The program I use like server FTP is **vsftpd**, but I'ave try also **ProFTPD** with the same problem.

Here some test:

server FTP  on linux system  ProFTPD (with vsftpd is very similar result)

----------------Test connection 1:
client SyncBackFree on Windows 10 32bit

```
13/01/2019 03:48:33: SyncBackFree V8.5.97.0  
13/01/2019 03:48:33: Windows 10 build 17134  
13/01/2019 03:48:33: Resolving host name "82.**.**.**"  
13/01/2019 03:48:33: Connecting to 82.**.**.** Port: 25  
13/01/2019 03:48:33: Connected to 82.**.**.**.    
13/01/2019 03:48:34: 220 ProFTPD 1.3.5a Server (MaxServerFtp) [192.168.1.8]  
13/01/2019 03:48:34: USER odroid  
13/01/2019 03:48:34: 331 Password required for odroid  
13/01/2019 03:48:34: PASS (hidden)  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: 230 User odroid logged in  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: SYST  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: 215 UNIX Type: L8  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: Detected Server Type: UNIX  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: RTT: 26.404 ms 
13/01/2019 03:48:35: FEAT  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: 211-Features:  
13/01/2019 03:48:35: SITE MKDIR  
13/01/2019 03:49:36: Timeout (60s).  
13/01/2019 03:49:36: 3  
13/01/2019 03:49:36: Client closed the connection.
```

---------------Test connection 2:
freefilesync on Windows 10 32bit

```
CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT: server response timeout  
SITE MKDIR [curl_easy_perform]
```

---------------Test connection 3:
filezilla client  on Windows 10 32bit

```
Stato:  Connessione a 82.**.**.**:25...  
Stato:  Connessione stabilita, in attesa del messaggio di benvenuto...  
Stato:  Server non sicuro, non supporta FTP su TLS.  
Comando:    USER odroid  
Risposta:   331 Password required for odroid  
Comando:    PASS **************  
Risposta:   230 User odroid logged in  
Comando:    SYST  
Risposta:   215 UNIX Type: L8  
Comando:    FEAT  
Risposta:   211-Features:  
Risposta:    SITE MKDIR  
Errore: Timeout connessione dopo 20 secondi di inattività  
Errore: Impossibile collegarsi al server  
Stato:  In attesa di un nuovo tentativo...  
Stato:  Connessione a 82.**.**.**:25...  
Stato:  Connessione stabilita, in attesa del messaggio di benvenuto...  
Risposta:   220 ProFTPD 1.3.5a Server (MaxServerFtp) [192.168.1.8]  
Comando:    AUTH TLS  
Risposta:   500 AUTH not understood  
Comando:    AUTH SSL  
Risposta:   500 AUTH not understood  
Stato:  Server non sicuro, non supporta FTP su TLS.  
Comando:    USER odroid  
Risposta:   331 Password required for odroid  
Comando:    PASS **************  
Risposta:   230 User odroid logged in  
Comando:    FEAT  
Risposta:   211-Features:  
Risposta:    SITE MKDIR  
Errore: Tentativo di connessione interrotto dall'utente
```

---

Here log example of  connection successful from client win7 to server   ProFTPD linux:

```
Connecting to 82.**.**.**, Port 25  
220 ProFTPD 1.3.5a Server (MaxServerFtp) [192.168.1.8]  
USER odroid  
331 Password required for odroid  
PASS (hidden)  
230 User odroid logged in  
FEAT  
211-Features:  
 SITE MKDIR  
 MFF modify;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;  
 REST STREAM  
 MLST   modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;  
 UTF8  
 EPRT  
 SITE SYMLINK  
 EPSV  
 SITE UTIME  
 LANG it-IT.UTF-8;it-IT;en-US.UTF-8;en-US*  
 MDTM  
 SITE RMDIR  
 TVFS  
 SITE COPY  
 MFMT  
 SIZE  
211 End    
OPTS UTF8 ON  
200 UTF8 set to on  
REST 0  
350 Restarting at 0. Send STORE or RETRIEVE to initiate transfer  
PWD  
257 "/home/odroid" is the current directory  
CWD /var/www/test/htdocs  
250 CWD command successful  
TYPE A  
200 Type set to A  
PASV  
227 Entering Passive Mode (82.**.**.**,156,201).  
MLSD  
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for MLSD  
226 Transfer complete
```

Can someone help me?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Davide